# Windows Batch file nested IF statement running both IF and THEN

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Not sure why this nested IF statement won't work right.  I can't find any issues with it.  The Last code block actually works properly, not sure why the first one doesn't.

The first script is running the first tracert, but also printing out the ELSE command of the main IF statement as well.  The second instance of this same code in my script (identical, except for having sCSHOSTNAME instead of sCSCLIENTNAME) just prints out the else command of the main IF statement.

```
sCSCLIENTNAME is a remote server address
sCSHOSTNAME is a remote server address
dBASEHOME is the root folder where the cvping file exists
DIAGFolder is a destination folder where all of the outputs are being dumpe
```

The tracert line (the one with a bunch of variables) works fine alone, leaving those lines out to not make this too long.

```
IF EXIST sCSCLIENTNAME (
   ECHO Checking network connectivity to %sCSCLIENTNAME%...
   ::cvping
   IF EXIST "%dBASEHOME%\cvping.exe" (
     "%dBASEHOME%\cvping" %sCSCLIENTNAME%> "%DIAGFolder%\cvping.txt"
   ) ELSE (
     @ECHO CVPing test skipped due to cvping not being found>> "%DIAGFolder%\cvping.txt"
   )
   ::ping
   ping %sCSCLIENTNAME%>> "%DIAGFolder%\PingResults.txt"
   :: Traceroute
   (9>"%lockFile%" tracert %sCSCLIENTNAME%>> "%DIAGFolder%\traceroute.txt") | <nul >nul 2>&1 (cmd /v /q /c "%loop% ( %wait% & %rotateSpin% & (( %check% )&&( %atEnd% )||( %progress% )))")
) ELSE (
  ECHO sCSCLIENTNAME not defined in registry, skipping tests to that value...>> "%DIAGFolder%\PingResults.txt"
  ECHO sCSCLIENTNAME not defined in registry, skipping tests to that value...>> "%DIAGFolder%\traceroute.txt"
)
```

Oddly enough, the following actually works:

```
IF DEFINED dBASEHOME (
   ECHO\
   ECHO Checking network connectivity to %sCSHOSTNAME%...
   ::CVPING
   IF EXIST "%dBASEHOME%\cvping.exe" "%dBASEHOME%\cvping" %sCSHOSTNAME%> "%DIAGFolder%\cvping.txt"
   ::ping
   ping %sCSHOSTNAME%>> "%DIAGFolder%\PingResults.txt"
   :: Traceroute
   (9>"%lockFile%" tracert %sCSHOSTNAME%>> "%DIAGFolder%\traceroute.txt") | <nul >nul 2>&1 (cmd /v /q /c "%loop% ( %wait% & %rotateSpin% & (( %check% )&&( %atEnd% )||( %progress% )))")
   ECHO\
   ECHO Checking network connectivity to %sCSCLIENTNAME%...
   IF EXIST "%dBASEHOME%\cvping.exe" "%dBASEHOME%\cvping" %sCSCLIENTNAME%> "%DIAGFolder%\cvping.txt"
   ping %sCSCLIENTNAME%>> "%DIAGFolder%\PingResults.txt"
   (9>"%lockFile%" tracert %sCSCLIENTNAME%>> "%DIAGFolder%\traceroute.txt") | <nul >nul 2>&1 (cmd /v /q /c "%loop% ( %wait% & %rotateSpin% & (( %check% )&&( %atEnd% )||( %progress% )))")
   ECHO\
) ELSE (
   ECHO No defined servers found, skipping network connectivity tests.
   ECHO Traceroutes not run due to Application not appearing to be installed>  "%DIAGFolder%\No_Tracert.txt"
)
```

I started with the bottom code, then split it into 2 IF statements, checking for sCSCLIENTNAME and sCSHOSTNAME separately (I only put one of the IF statements above, the other is exactly the same, but different variable), but also put an IF statement in on the cvping line to determine if that file existed first.

Self contained code sample...

```
@ECHO OFF
cls

SET sCSCLIENTNAME=localhost
SET sCSHOSTNAME=www.google.com
SET dBASEHOME=%SystemRoot%\system32
SET DIAGFolder=%temp%\%computername%
rmdir "%DIAGFolder%" /s /q >nul 2>&1
mkdir "%DIAGFolder%" >nul 2>&1

IF EXIST sCSHOSTNAME (
   ECHO\
   ECHO Checking network connectivity to %sCSHOSTNAME%...
   ::CVPING
   IF EXIST "%dBASEHOME%\cvping.exe" (
    "%dBASEHOME%\cvping" %sCSHOSTNAME%> "%DIAGFolder%\cvping.txt"
   ) ELSE (
    @ECHO CVPing test to %sCSHOSTNAME% skipped due to cvping not being found> "%DIAGFolder%\cvping.txt"
   )
   ::ping
   ping %sCSHOSTNAME%>> "%DIAGFolder%\PingResults.txt"
   :: Traceroute
   tracert %sCSHOSTNAME%>> "%DIAGFolder%\traceroute.txt"
) ELSE (
  ECHO sCSHOSTNAME not defined in registry, skipping tests to that value...>> "%DIAGFolder%\PingResults.txt"
  ECHO sCSHOSTNAME not defined in registry, skipping tests to that value...>> "%DIAGFolder%\traceroute.txt"
)

IF EXIST sCSCLIENTNAME (
   ECHO Checking network connectivity to %sCSCLIENTNAME%...
   ::CVPING
   IF EXIST "%dBASEHOME%\cvping.exe" (
     "%dBASEHOME%\cvping" %sCSCLIENTNAME%> "%DIAGFolder%\cvping.txt"
   ) ELSE (
     @ECHO CVPing test skipped due to cvping not being found>> "%DIAGFolder%\cvping.txt"
   )
   ::ping
   ping %sCSCLIENTNAME%>> "%DIAGFolder%\PingResults.txt"
   :: Traceroute
   tracert %sCSCLIENTNAME%>> "%DIAGFolder%\traceroute.txt"
) ELSE (
  ECHO sCSCLIENTNAME not defined in registry, skipping tests to that value...>> "%DIAGFolder%\PingResults.txt"
  ECHO sCSCLIENTNAME not defined in registry, skipping tests to that value...>> "%DIAGFolder%\traceroute.txt"
)
pause
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `IF DEFINED sCSCLIENTNAME (`?

Comment: If I used "DEFINED" instead of "EXIST", I get an error of `( was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: I added a self contained code sample to my original post to make it easy to see the issue.